# What does this CSS selector mean?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why is the following code like this?

```
div div {background: #A4CA39}
```

Ignore the background color. I pulled this from the odin project android logo walkthrough.  This code was put at the top of the css sheet. Wondering why its `div div` and not just `div`?

Comment: Please do not write your CSS like this... This is horribly bad, and will create all kinds of issues later on. Use a class on the div instead.

Answer (score 1):

`div div` matches all `div` elements that are inside another `div`
Something like this:

```
<div>
    <div></div> <-- this one is matched by the CSS rule
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`div div { /* style */ }` applies styles to any `div` that is inside another `div`

Comment: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-android-logo                                                       Here, when i remove the one div the green area gets bigger...trying to understand how that works.  i understand that div div applies styles to any div inside...but why is it that when i remove div from "div div" that the green area gets bigger?

Comment: If you remove the second `div` then the rule applies to all `div`s at all levels, and not just those that descend from a `div` parent.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999999;
}
div div {
    background: #A4CA39;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The `div {}` rule will apply to the outer `<div>`. The `div div {}` rule will apply to the inner one, and will create a smaller greenish square inside the bigger grey square.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mf8k8qL2/) to test.

Comment: `div {}` apply on both but `div div {}` override the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

The `div div{}` represents the child `div` of a parent `div` being targeted with certain styles. Just one `div{}` means that ALL `<div>` tags in the page are styled, rather than just the children. So for your current code, the background color will only be applied to `div` elements inside other `div` elements, while if it was just 1 `div`, every single `div` tag would have the same background color.